# How to add a checkbox in my checkbox column using datagridview windowsform in VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

```
Private Sub Recipients_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = <SQL> SELECT Idno,Name,YearSec,Course,Organization FROM tbl_students </SQL>.Value

    Dim myadap As New MySqlDataAdapter(mycom)
    Dim mydt As New DataTable

    mydt.Columns.Add("", GetType(Boolean))
    myadap.Fill(mydt)
    grdRecipients.DataSource = mydt

    myadap.Dispose()

End Sub
```

I have a problem creating a checkbox in the header of my checkbox column, which will supposed to be a checkbox so that i can check all the rows which are present in the data gridview.
Any answer will greatly help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn c1;
    CheckBox ckBox;

   grdRecipients.DataSource = mydt

   ckBox = new CheckBox();

  //Get the column header cell bounds
  Rectangle rect =
  this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);
  ckBox.Size = new Size(18, 18);

  //Change the location of the CheckBox to make it stay on the header
  ckBox.Location = rect.Location;
  ckBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(ckBox_CheckedChanged);

  //Add the CheckBox into the DataGridView
  this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(ckBox);
```

Below method use to check uncheck all checkbox

```
     void ckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
        {
            this.dataGridView1[0, j].Value = this.ckBox.Checked;
        }
        this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
```